.htaccess not accessible in php docker
I have a project with a php docker that I make work with this code:
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  www:
    image: php:7.4.30-apache
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    build: .

Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4.30-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
RUN a2enmod rewrite


index.php
<?php

echo "hello world";

.htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)--([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ title.php?title=$1&title_id=$2

RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

but when I go to the site, I get this:
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

This is usually caused by a permissions problem. That docker image will send all Apache server errors to the Docker log stream. Follow the log stream (docker compose logs -f) or run the project in the foreground (docker compose up without -d), then access your site. What error appears in the server logs?

"permissions problem" refers to a problem with file permissions here inside the file system.
